# Add author's name automatically while building ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I, along with a few others, am writing a project report, where different subsections have been authored by different people. When I build the table of contents using the `\tableofcontents` tag, it would be really helpful if the subsection names could bear with them the name of the authors in tiny letters. Is this possible? We are using the documentclass `article`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could define a command for this purpose, making use of the optional argument of the sectioning commands. In the example below `\autsection` has two mandatory arguments: the first one for the section title and the second one for the authors (of course, make the format adjustments that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\autsection[2]{%
  \section[#1~/ {\normalfont\small\itshape#2}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\autsection{Strategies against widows}{Paul Isamber}

\autsection{The exact placement of superscripts and subscripts}{Joseph Wright and Timothy Hall}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfect for me in memoir. How would I add the descripton to the section as well, a la chapterprecis?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out myself. Probably very hacky, though:

    `\newcommand\mysection[2]{%
\section[#1~/ {\normalfont\small\itshape#2}]{#1}{\hspace{3em}\normalfont\small\itshape#2\\\\}}`